# Scala macros invoke a compile-time determined function name

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I have the following code:

```scala
def invokeFunction(logger: Logger, fName: String) = macro invokeFunctionImpl

//...

def invokeFunctionImpl(c: Context)(logger: c.Expr[Logger], fName: c.Expr[String]) ={
  import c.universe._
  // i'd like to invoke: logger.${fName}("some message")
}
```

Another problem I'm facing is naming a function during compile-time, using a given argument:

```scala
def createFunction(fName: String) = macro createFunctionImpl

//...

def createFunctionImpl(c: Context)(fName: c.Expr[String], param: c.Expr[String]) ={
  import c.universe._
  // i'd like to create: def functionNamed${fName}(param: [paramType]) = {
    // implementation unimportant
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use macros for that? If the `fName` in `invokeFunction` is actually a `String` value, then writing `invokeFunction` should be impossible without runtime reflection (`logger.getClass.getMethod(fName).invoke(logger)`). But if `fName` is a literal (`Singleton`) then you probably can just make normal function calls. Maybe you can consider using `scala.Dynamic`, or create a `Map[String, Logger => Unit]` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`invokeFunction` should be like

```
def invokeFunction(logger: Logger, fName: String): Unit = macro invokeFunctionImpl

def invokeFunctionImpl(c: blackbox.Context)(logger: c.Expr[Logger], fName: c.Expr[String]): c.Expr[Unit] ={
  import c.universe._
  val q"${fNameStr: String}" = fName.tree
  c.Expr(q"""$logger.${TermName(fNameStr)}("some message")""")
}
```

I added return type. I assume that `fName` is a compile-time `String` literal (otherwise you'll have `MatchError`).

Regarding `createFunction` try

```
def createFunction(fName: String, param: String): Unit = macro createFunctionImpl

def createFunctionImpl(c: blackbox.Context)(fName: c.Expr[String], param: c.Expr[String]): c.Expr[Unit] ={
  import c.universe._
  val q"${fNameStr: String}" = fName.tree
  val q"${paramNameStr: String}" = param.tree

  c.Expr(q"""
    def ${TermName(fNameStr)}(${TermName(paramNameStr)}: ParamType) = ???

    ()
  """)
}
```

Please notice that signatures of macro and its implementation must correspond to each other. So I added `param` to `createFunction`. And I added return type. Also it's important that a function being created will be accessible only inside the block that our macro is expanded to. New definitions is not what [def macros](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html) are normally intended for ([macro annotations](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html) are).

I'm not sure I understand completely what you're doing. It will be easier to answer if you provide code how you're going to use your macros.

Comment: I have added a tracing capability (events to datadog) that calls a macro. Also, we have regular logging. Sometimes tracing and logging correlate and we need to call trace and log functions one after the other. I wanted to create a macro function that handles this with one call. For that, I need to create `debugAndTrace`, `infoAndTrace`, `warnAndTrace` etc, functions. I wanted to use macros for that also.

Comment: @MaxG Do you understand that functions created with def macro will exist only inside the block that this macro is expanded to? (The def macro will expand to a block like `{ ...; def someFunction() = ???; ... }` with curly braces `{ }`.) Is it ok for your use case?

Comment: No, I understand that I'll have to use macro annotations as well for that use case, right? B/C I need these `xAndTrace` functions to exist in a util of sorts.

Comment: @MaxG Right, you need macro annotations, not def macros.

Comment: I'll post the full code in another question if I won't be able to get the idea. Thanks for your help.